# Validating your site

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, validation

What else needs to be validated apart from what I have below? This is my question.

It is important that any input to a site is properly validated:

- Textboxes, etc – use .NET validators (or custom code if the validators aren’t appropriate)
- Querystring or Form values  – use manual validation (casting to specific types, boundary checking, etc)

This ties into the problems which XSS can reveal.

Basically you have to validate any input that someone could potentially tamper with:

- Form Postbacks (mainly .NET Controls – these can be validated with .NET validation controls. Also if you have Request Validation turned on on all pages, this reduces the risk )
- QueryString Values
- Cookie values
- HTTP Headers
- Viewstate (automatically done for you as long as you have ViewState MAC enabled)
- Javascript (all JS can be viewed and changed, so need to ensure no crucial functionality is handled by JavaScript- i.e. always enable server side validation)

Comment: agreed evil users must be stopped

Comment: Seems like you have it all covered, I would turn off javascript in the browser and make sure that all the functionality is still operational and any malicious input can be handled in server side code

Comment: Everything that could ever come from a malicious source - which is actually everything that is sent to the server, including URLs.

Comment: @ atornblad yeah the malicious part would be the query strings in the urls you right.

Comment: @Anicho its not clear what else you are looking for or how it relates to your security strategy.

Comment: @Rook not much else just want to see by end of play friday if anyone else can point anything else out. I believe you have covered most of it in which case you will get answer checked off :).

Comment: Well, when dealing with requests... sometimes times I use `if(Request.IsLocal)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot that can go wrong with a web application.  Your list is pretty comprehensive, although it is duplication.  The http spec only states,  GET, POST, Cookie and Header.  There are many different types of POST,  but its all in the same part of the request.

For your list I would also add everything having to do with file upload,  which is a type of POST.  For instance,  file name,  mime type and the contents of the file.  I would fire up a network monitoring application like Wireshark and everything in the request should be considered potentially harmful.

There will never be a one size fits all validation function.  If you are merging sql injection and xss sanitation functions then you maybe in trouble.  I recommend testing your site using automation. A free service like [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About) or an open source tool like [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) will detect methods of attack that you have missed.

Also,  on a side note.  Passing the view state around with a MAC and/or encrypted is a gross misuse of cryptography.  Cryptography is tool used when there is no other solution.  By using a MAC or encryption you are opening the door for an attacker to brute force this value or use something like oracle padding attack to take advantage of you.  A view state should be kept track by the server, period end of story.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on view state and mac, I will look into this further.

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you keep MAC validation enabled at all times. It works well to prevent spoofing attacks, i.e. when an attacker feeds values that you normally don't allow. Source: http://aspnetresources.com/articles/ViewState

Comment: @Anicho  I'm not saying to disable the mac on a viewstate,  I'm saying its a fundamentally insecure approach to the problem.   Whowever came up withe this idea of a viewstate doesn't understand security.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, helped a bunch :). gotta wait 3 more hours sigh.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different way of looking at the problem that is orthogonal to what you have here (and hence not incompatible, there's no reason why you can't examine it both ways in case you catch with one what you miss with another).

The two things that are important in any validation are:

1. Things you pay attention to.
2. Things you pass to another layer untouched.

Now, most of the things you've mentioned so far fit into the first cateogry. Cookies that you ignore fit into the second, as would query & post information if you passed to another handler with Server.Execute or similar.

The second category is the most debatable.

On the one hand, if a given handler (.aspx page, IHttpHandler, etc.) ignores a cookie that may be used by another handler at some point in the future, it's mostly up to that other handler to validate it.

On the other hand, it's always good to have an approach that assumes other layers have security holes and you shouldn't trust them to be correct, even if you wrote them yourself (especially if you wrote them yourself!)

A middle-ground position, is that if there are perhaps 5 different states some persistant data could validly be in, but only 3 make sense when a particular piece of code is hit, it might verify that it is in one of those 3 states, even if that doesn't pose a risk to that particular code.

That done, we'll concentrate on the first category.

Querystrings, form-data, post-backs, headers and cookies all fall under the same category of stuff that came from the user (whether they know it or not). Indeed, they are sometimes different ways of looking at the same thing.

Of this, there is a subset that we will actually work upon in any way.

Of that there is a range of legal values for each such item.

Of that, there is a range of legal combinations of values for the items as a whole.

Validation therefore becomes a matter of:

1. Identify what input we will act upon.
2. Make sure that each component of that input is valid in its own right.
3. Make sure that the combinations are valid (e.g it may be valid to not send a credit card number, but invalid to not send one but set payment type to "credit card").

Now, when we come to this, it's generally best not to try to catch certain attacks. For example, it's not so good to avoid `'` in values that will be passed to SQL. Rather, we have three possibilities:

1. It's invalid to have `'` in the value because it doesn't belong there (e.g. a value that can only be "true" or "false", or from a set list of values in which none of them contain `'`). Here we catch the fact that it isn't in the set of legal values, and ignore the precise nature of the attack (thus being protected also from other attacks we don't even know about!).
2. It's valid as human input, but not as what we will use. An example here is a large number (in some cultures `'` is used to separate thousands). Here we canonicalise both "123,456,789" and "123'456'789" to 123456789 and don't care what it was like before that, as long as we can meaningfully do so (the input wasn't "fish" or a number that is out of the range of legal values for the case in hand).
3. It's valid input. If your application blocks apostrophes in name fields in an attempt to block SQL-injection, then it's buggy because there are real names with apostrophes out there. In this case we consider "d'Eath" and "O'Grady" to be valid input and deal with the fact that `'` is significant in SQL by escaping properly (ideally by using an API for data access that will do this for us.

A classic example of the third point with ASP.NET is code that blocks "suspicious" input with `<` and `>` - something that makes a great number of ASP.NET pages buggy. Granted, it's better to be buggy in blocking that inappropriately than buggy by accepting it inappropriately, but the defaults are for people who haven't thought about validation and trying to stop them from hurting themselves too badly. Since you *are* thinking about validation, you should consider whether it's appropriate to turn that automatic validation off and then treat `<` and `>` in a manner appropriate for your given use.

Note also that I haven't said anything about javascript. I don't validate javascript (unless perhaps I was actually *receiving* it), I ignore it. I pretend it doesn't exist and then I won't miss a case where its validation could be tampered with. Pretend yours doesn't exist at this layer too. Ultimately client-side validation is to save the good guys making honest mistakes time, not to twart the bad guys.

For similar reasons, this is best not tested through a browser. Use Fiddler to construct requests that hit the validation points you want to examine. This way all client-side validation is by-passed, and you're looking at the server the same way an attacker will.

Finally, remember that a page with 100% perfect validation is not necessarily secure. E.g. if your validation is perfect but your authentication poor then someone can send "valid" code to it that will be just - perhaps more - nasty as the more classic SQL-injection of XSS code. That hits onto other topics that are for other questions, except that validation as discussed here is only part of the puzzle.